# jQuery can't call plugins after appending Ajax data?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins, jquery

**EDIT2:** Nevermind, got it working. jQuery was included again in one of the scripts called with ajax. Thanks anyway.

**EDIT:** This is a rephrased question. Took my a while to find where the problem was.
Calls to plugin functions (including UI effect) aren't working after I load some content with ajax.

The original question had `.effect("pulsate",{},1000)` call, which explains sarcastyxs answer. Now I'm trying the same thing with the countdown plugin. The same problem appears.

Here is my code. Ignore that it doesn't do much sense, it is stripped down from a larger file. By itself the code is fine. For instance, if I call `fadeOut()` it works, but if I use `.countdown` or `.effect` the mentioned problem appears.

```
var getOrderDetails= function(id){
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "orderDetails.php",
        data: {id: id}, 
        success: function(data){
            //$("#orderDetails").html(data);
            $("#orderDetails").unbind().click(function(){
                var status = $("#orderDetails .orderStatus").text()
                acceptOrder(id, status);
            });
        }
    });
}

var acceptOrder = function(id, status){         
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "orderStatus.php",
        data: {action: 'set', id: id, status: status}, 
        success: function(data){
            var nowTime = new Date();
            var countdownTime = nowTime.setMinutes(nowTime.getMinutes() + 2);
            $("#waitingOrders").countdown({until: countdownTime, compact:true, format: 'MS'});
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".order").unbind().click(function() {
        var id = $(this).find(".orderId").text();
        getOrderDetails(id);
    });
});
```

When I comment the `$("#orderDetails").html(data)` line (like in code), the countdown timer appears inside the `orderDetails` div.
When I uncomment the line, I get an `countdown is not a function` error. Looked at the dom in firebug, and really in first case I can see that the selector has the .countdown function, and in the second scenario it does not.

What am I missing here?
Someone please help, I have been stuck on this for a few days.
Tried to wrap the ajax success functions with another function and pass it `this` as context, but it doesn't help. Same thing

Comment: Are your 'containter*' ID'ed elements intentionally misspelled? Are your three `<div>`s really siblings of #containter1? Should the `.remove()` come before the `.prepend()`?

Comment: The code is fine. This is the simplified version. Sorry if there are any misspellings, but it works fine. If I replace the pulsate with a simple fadeOut everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some core functions from `jquery-ui`. You can download a custom `jquery-ui` library from [the jQuery site](http://jqueryui.com/download).

You basically want to select `Effects core` and whatever other effect you want to use on the site. The `effects core` is not part of the default jQuery ui library for some reason.

Comment: ok. i'll try. but how would that explain that the effect (with same code) works in another part of the file

Comment: @ZolaKt, You mean the `pulsate` effect?

Comment: @sarcasryx: Yes. This line: $(this).find("div.div1, div.div2, div.div3").effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 1000);   Just it is not $(this) but another selector

Comment: No idea. JQuery quirkiness maybe. But in my test example the default `jquery-ui` library didn't have the pulsate function and I had to get a custom `jquery-ui` library to get the `pulsate` function to work.

Comment: I have the custom library jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js

Comment: @ZolaKt, So it works when it is not part of the Ajax callback?

Comment: I think callback is the problem, not necessarily ajax

Comment: This is the simplest example I could create with similar code http://jsfiddle.net/sarcastyx/t2Bw9/3/ and it is working without any problems. Maybe you might have to `console.log` all the variables to see where it is breaking.

Comment: I edited the question. I found what is causing the behavior, but am no closer to finding a solution